# Deployed React website tries to fetch from server instead of rendering a component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, routes

For example, /new works fine with localhost (server using localhost:5000 and client 3000). However, after deployed on Heroku, by clicking the "Add new" link from the Navigation bar (with bootstrap and added as {Link} part), the page is rendered as expected, but if I refresh the page, it shows "cannot get /new" since it is trying to fetch from server (there is no such API from server).
[by clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhYwI.png)
[by refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykGJ2.png)

The website is deployed by running "npm run build" and building react client into the /public folder of server (Express node.js).

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you're refreshing the page the browser sends request to your heroku server to fetch that path.

While you want the browser to reload your React app route.

To fix that you'll need to:

1. Prepend your api endpoints definition with `/api` prefix, for instance `/api/coaches`.
2. Update your React app code to make api requests to updated enpoints.
3. Add this code to your express server **after** your endpoints definitions:

`app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve('build', 'index.html'));`